# How to config mass network interfaces with same option?

Tags: networking, debian, sr-iov

I have a SR-IOV enabled debian which exposed 128 VF network interfaces. I would like to configure all of these VF with MTU=9000 and some other options, but won't like to copy same config line 127 times in **/etc/network/interface** file.

Is there any programmatic way to do a looping or similar configuration?

I have found a config directory in **/etc/network/interface.d**, but don't know how can I accomplish it?

Any advice are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a hook to `/etc/network/ifup.d` containing something like:

`#! /bin/sh
echo "$IFACE" | grep -qs vf || exit 0
ip link set "$IFACE" mtu 9000`

Make sure to make the hook executable, adjust the exact settings to what you want, adjust the `grep` to match the interfaces you want.  The name of the hook also has to match the patterns required by `run-parts`.